# Downgrade from iOS 15.4 to older archived backup possible?

Tags: ios, restore

I have recently upgraded to iOS 15.4.  The upgrade has made my hearing aid app not work properly. Apple blames the developer and the developer blames Apple.  Anyway, I'd like to use the app as it has functionality that the native apple accessibility program doesnt have.  Is it possible to restore iPhone to archived 15.1 back up I have?  If so, how?  Here is the archived info:

[image: 1]

and here are 2 files I found in the trash:

[image: 2]

Confused why one read 15.1 and the other 15.1.1, but this is what I have.  Tks

Comment: I'm afraid Apple stopped signing 15.3.1 three days ago [anything older will have stopped earlier]. This makes rollback no longer possible.

Comment: Aghhhh.  The app does not connect to the hearing aids on 15.4 making it unusable.  What a drag.  Thank you